# Missing rows in query

Tags: mysql

This is how my query looks so far:

```
SELECT activity_name AS 'Activity', child_gender AS 'Gender',
COUNT(*) AS 'Total'
FROM Child C, Child_Activities D, Activity A
WHERE D.child_id=C.child_id
AND D.activity_id=A.activity_id
GROUP BY A.activity_id;
```

For some reason the activity_type only comes up once with one gender only. I need it to display both genders (M & F) on 2 rows (or 2 columns) per activity. Any ideas?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT activity_name AS 'Activity', child_gender AS 'Gender',
COUNT(*) AS 'Total'
FROM Child C, Child_Activities D, Activity A
WHERE D.child_id=C.child_id
AND D.activity_id=A.activity_id
GROUP BY A.activity_id, child_Gender;
```

Missing gender in group by: mySQL requires it otherwise it assumes you don't care about the gender and randomly selects one.

See [this article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) for more info
and [this article too](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html)

Specifically from the 2nd article: You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses.